# How BPM Workflow will be implemented in Micro Services

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, business-process-management

I am implementing Spring Micro Services application, here we have a requirement to initiate a workflow by using Software AG.

to achieve this, I have two approaches.

From UI layer I will directly call BPM and BPM will call my Micro services after initiation.
My second approach here is From UI I will call my Microservices and then I will call BPM.
here I would call BPM for both Initiation and update the task so can anybody please suggest me which approach is best the one.

Which approach I should go on which case

what are the Pros and Cons for both the approaches.

if any suggestions would be a great help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest UI layer directly calling BPM. You should call micro-service first so that you have complete control in future of any changes. You can put all validations here in micro-service and then call BPM.

Always to external client; we expose an interface.. an agreement..which won't change ever and is very minimalistic.

Comment: hi deepak, thanks for for your reply, can give some example those which are not possible to do at BPM side, so that it should be done at micro service side. and that kind of control that only we can achieve in micro service not possible at BPM.